# How are MVC Data models populated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with an ASP.NET 6 MVC Application and have this method to retrieve the "Add" view in my controller.

```cs
        // GET: Operations/Bookings/Add
        public IActionResult Add()
        {
            ViewData["ClientList"] = _context.Clients.ToList<Client>();
            ViewData["CountryList"] = _context.Countries.ToList<Country>();

            return View();
        }
```

We use `ViewData["ClientList"]` to retrieve the complete list of clients for the user to choose which one to associate the new "booking" record with:

[image: Screenshot]

```razor
<fieldset>
    <div class="card mb-0">
        <div class="card-body table-responsive p-0">
            <table class="table table-sm table table-striped table-hover text-nowrap">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th style="width: 250px">City</th>
                        <th style="width: 250px">Country</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var Item in ViewBag.ClientList)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="icheck-primary d-inline">
                                <input asp-for="ClientId" id="@Item.Id" type="radio" name="ClientItem" value="@Item.Id" />
                                <label for="@Item.Id" class="w-100" style="font-weight: 400">@Item.CompanyName</label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="@Item.Id" class="w-100 mb-0" style="font-weight: 400">
                                @Item.City
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="@Item.Id" class="w-100 mb-0" style="font-weight: 400">
                                <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-@Item.Country.CountryCode.ToLower() table-icon"></span>
                                @Item.Country.CountryName
                            </label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

 - 

}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Here are the Booking, Client, and Country Models:

```cs
public class Bookings
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Client")]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public virtual Client? Client { get; set; }

    //Truncated

    // . . .
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    // Address
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = " ")]
    public string? Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string County { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Country")]
    public int CountryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Country? Country { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    //Truncated

    // . . .   
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

What is confusing me here is how simply adding `ViewData["CountryList"]` to the controller code causes the Client's `Country` Object/Property to be populated with the correct data. If I remove the line of code, this Country object is null and requesting the page results in an error because I'm asking for information from a null object. This I expect.

I inserted a breakpoint on `return View();` to be able to inspect the values. Note how the `CountryId` has its int value as stored in the database, but without the `ViewData["CountryList"]` line, the Country object is null. For clarity, Country ID 234 in my dataset is the United Kingdom, matching the country shown in the first screenshot.

With `ViewData["CountryList"]`
[image: With ViewData]

Without `ViewData["CountryList"]`
[image: Without ViewData]

How is the correct country data populated? I can't see how I refer to `ViewData["CountryList"]` in my View or any other way the `Country` property within the Client is populated using this ViewData member. Are there some inner workings within MVC that handle this for me? Is it something that shouldn't work yet somehow does work?

Comment: to put it short, you are asking why `@Item.Country` is `null`?

Comment: There could be something wrong with your lazy loading of navigation properties, it's apparently disabled. Normally, ef should just auto lazy load a navigation property when code asks for it. Here it looks like the country dbset has to be manually initialized before and only then nav properties work. I guess you could even not store countries in the view data but just load the dbset. Assuming it's ef core rather than the regular ef, it could be the default behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on Entity Framework's documentation. Specifically on [querying related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager), it says:

> Entity Framework Core **will automatically fix-up navigation properties** to any other entities that were previously loaded into the context instance. So even if you don't explicitly include the data for a navigation property, the property may still be populated if some or all of the related entities were previously loaded.

If you want to have more implicit control over what you want to load, you can use [`Include`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels). Something like:

```
ViewData["ClientList"] = _context.Clients
                                 .Include(client => client.Country)
                                 .ToList<Client>();
```

Should do the tricks.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there some inner workings within MVC that handle this for me?

@Wiktor Zychla 's comment is right, you can read  [Read related data - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0#learn-how-to-load-related-data) to know more.

> When the entity is first read, related data isn't retrieved. However,
> the first time you attempt to access a navigation property, the data
> required for that navigation property is automatically retrieved. A
> query is sent to the database each time you try to get data from a
> navigation property for the first time.

> How is the correct country data populated?

If you use With `ViewData["CountryList"]`,  you can get the result.
If you use Without `ViewData["CountryList"]`, avoiding  Country object is null, you could use `Include`. These are two ways to get the result.